# ALSA Check if spdif plugged in / active

Tags: audio, alsa, c++

Is there any way in alsa / libasound to check whether the SPDIF In actually has a device connected?
I'm currently using a Raspberry Pi with an USB sound card to merge the audio from my PC coming in over SPDIF with the audio of the Pi before outputting it to my speakers.
The problem is that if I turn off my PC or set it to sleep, the speakers start making knocking noises for a few seconds before going silent and my program is getting tons of capture buffer overruns.
Hence, I need to check if there's actually a device connected before reading the PCM input.

Comment: Apparently, your hardware does not provide samples when SPDIF is inactive. Check for that.

Comment: The problem is that initially it does get more samples. I've checked `arecord -vv -f dat /dev/null` and the bar goes up to 98%.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution albeit not the optimal one I was hoping for.
If someone has an idea, I'd be glad to hear it.
Until then I'll handle the issue as follows:

I've noticed that the rate of the samples coming in drops when the cable is removed. I hope the same is the case when the computer turns off but I think that's pretty safe to assume.
Anyhow, to find out whether to play or to ignore the stream I've used chrono's `high_precision_clock` to time the interval between 20 periods.
In each period I collect the amount of samples read using `snd_pcm_readi` (I'm using nonblocking mode and a timeout to prevent getting stuck in the reading process for longer than a period should take).
Finally, I calculate the sample rate and if it differs from my expected sample rate by more than 2kHz, I ignore the stream until  it gets back into the expected range again.